# Android Wear Authorization not Working

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-wear-2.0

I created an app for the Wear operating system. 
I used Android Studio 3.1.3 
In this app I inserted a button and on the click of this I would like the watch to vibrate. 
The problem is that the permissions of the app do not work.
I entered the request for vibration permission in the manifest, but when I start the app on the clock does not require me permissions and if I check the permissions registered for the app tells me that no authorization is required.
where am I wrong?
this is my manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ginetto.martinelli.warehousenotification">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:requiredFeature="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:requiredFeature="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: This code is from android phone app or watch app ?

Comment: You need to request permission from the wearable application.Follow this article https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions

Comment: Also this sample will help https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissionsWear